# Make code compatible with the latest version of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I integrated keyboard navigation on my site. When a visitor presses the "up" key or "bottom" of the keyboard on the page automatically scroll on a different rubric.

The problem is that this code is only compatible with jQuery 1.7.2 (and lower) and I have other codes that I need to implement with a more recent version.

What I need to modify this code to make it compatible with the latest version of jQuery ?

Pressing the up and down arrows on your keyboard: http://pepitodanger.free.fr/Maquette/

Thank you in advance.

```
function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.data-scroll');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { 
scroll = collection.get(i); 
break; 
 }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { 
scroll = collection.get(i-1); 
break; 
 }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 700       
        });
    }

    return false;
}


$(function() {
    $("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));    
    });
});


$(window).keydown (function(event) {
    if (event.altKey) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 78:  // Alt-N = next
            case 110: // Alt-n = next
                scroll ('next');
                break;
            case 80:  // Alt-P = prev
            case 112: // Alt-p = prev
                scroll ('prev');
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 37: // key is left
        case 38: // key is up
                scroll ('prev');
                break;
            case 39: // key is right
        case 40: // key is down
                scroll ('next');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tested it in newer versions of jQuery? What errors did you see? Have you looked at [the jQuery 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) and [migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your scrollTo plugin is out-of-date. Get the latest version from here: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: That's work ! Thank you. But now I will ask a new question cause I have an incompatibility.